# I do not want nuget to put files in root folder into the content folder?

Tags: webforms, teamcity, nuget, nuget-package

I have a .net webforms project and trying to create a nuget package. The project structure is like:

```
- Account (folder)
- Profile (folder)
- default.aspx
- web.config
```

I use Team City's "nuget pack", which successfully creates my project. But once after creating the package, my project three in the package becomes:

```
- Account
- Profile
- Content
-- default.aspx
-- web.config
- lib
-- .net45
-- .net45.dll
```

I do not want nuget to put files in root folder into the content folder. I want them to stay in the root. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found my answer. I just needed to use OctoPack which is available here:

http://octopusdeploy.com/documentation/integration/teamcity

Comment: Your answer is not relevant. It would be great to figure this out without installing TeamCity...